# SQL Update on selected rows from a lookup table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have tables structure like following:

```
Table1: BaseObject (ID, Name)

Table2: Instance (BaseObjectID, Type)

Table3: Mapping (Type, Value)
```

I want to

```
Update the BaseObject.Name = Mapping.Value 
where exists an Instance for the 
BaseObject (Instance.BaseObjectID = BaseObject.ID)
 and Mapping.Type = Instance.Type
```

Not able to figure out how to achieve this in SQL.

Edit:
Following works but i am not sure if it is optimal:

```
UPDATE BaseObject 
SET BaseObject.Name = (SELECT Mapping.Value 
                        FROM Mapping, Instance
                        WHERE Mapping.Type = Instance.Type
                        AND Instance.BaseObjectId = BaseObject.ID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Instance.BaseObjectID 
              FROM Instance 
              WHERE Instance.BaseObjectID = BaseObject.ID)
```

Comment: I am thinking of following but not sure what happens if inner query returns null (No Instance for BaseObject.ID):      UPDATE BaseObject 
SET BaseObject.Name = (SELECT Mapping.Value FROM Mapping, Instance WHERE Mapping.Type = Instance.Type AND Instance.BaseObjectId = BaseObject.ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE (SELECT t1.Name name, 
               t3.value value
          FROM BaseObject t1,
               Instance t2,
               Mapping t3
         WHERE t2.BaseObjectId = t1.ID
          AND  t3.Type = t2.Type)
   SET name = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. Note that it works only if there is at most one `Instance` for each `BaseObject`. Otherwise you have to define the logic according to which the appropriate name is chosen.

```
update BaseObject b
set name = (
  select m.value 
  from Instance i join Mapping m on (i.Type = m.Type)
  where BaseObjectID = b.ID 
)
where exists (
  select 1 
  from Instance i join Mapping m on (i.Type = m.Type)
  where BaseObjectID = b.ID 
)
```

Comment: Thanks Grisha. This is what i came up with but "where exists" is costly so wanted to avoid it.